# Remove whitespaces between braces within a string using Regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to figure out how to make a regex that can match spaces in between braces. So that these exact white spaces could be removed.

```
SOMETHING({ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 },{ 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 }, "My text with spaces)
```

should be come

```
SOMETHING({1,2,3,4,5},{2,4,6,8,10}, "My text with spaces)
```

I am not strong in regex and I tried to adapt the following function without luck. It gets the value between curly brackets, but I am not sure what to do to select only the white spaces between these brackets

```
str.replace(/[^{\}]+(?=})/g,'');
```

***Selected solution***

```
str.replace(/\s+(?=[^{}]*})/g,'');
```

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/TBgcPp/1 and certainly https://regex101.com/r/TBgcPp/1/codegen?language=javascript

Comment: I'd use this variant: [`str = str.replace(/\{[^}{]+}/g, m => m.replace(/ +/g, ''));`](https://tio.run/##RYxNC4JAGITv/oqhyyq9afaFEHaL6mAd6tYHiCxmrCnuYsXib99WOnQZZp5h5pG2qcyaolajNjLGEVxBqgYx2PGQrE/b3X7jaoSECWFKmBHm6Ej30foFISKEY4swSD5Q/K3wKtQdsk4zLj22dJzfn1W/4bWw2A0u@nzr9HXYBTmhRLxC@S8x7CljnmfHWfWUleC@qHLXXlhkzBc)

Comment: You can do :
    str.replace(\s+(?=[^}]*}), '') ;


Will work providing : 
Brackets are balanced
+ No brackets are nested